# Don't understand why this NameError: name 'null' is not defined exception occurs

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm testing a new code and I'm getting the error below. If I change the field "name: null" for something like "name: abc" it works. Any idea? How I can skip/workaround this "null" issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
data = [{"id": 111,
         "description": "",
         "name": null,
         "name_with_namespace": "Zzzz",
         "path": "Zzzz"
         },
        {"id": 222,
         "description": "",
         "name": "xp-demo-gradle",
         "name_with_namespace": "xp-demo-gradle",
         "path": "xp-demo-gradle"
         }]
for request in data:
    lista = []
    request["id"]
    paragraph = "id: " + str(request["id"]) + "; Path: " + request["path"] + "; Name: " + request["name"]
    artifact = {
        "requested_by": "RequestFetcher",
        "argument": {
            "topic": {
                "id": 2
                },
            "key": str(request["id"]),
            "title": "ID " + str(request["id"]),
            "text": paragraph,
            "cached": True,
            "_links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/projects/" + str(request["name"]),
                    "rel": "self",
                    "method": "GET"
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    lista.append(artifact)
    print(lista)
```

Comment: It's telling you `null` is a variable name that you haven't defined. You need to either quote it ("null") or define it as something

Comment: What do you expect `null` to be? It isn't defined anywhere, and is not a built-in python value. Perhaps you mean `None`

Comment: On this case, Null is the return of a json URL. I just hard coded the json output to test the code.

Comment: @rrudnicki _On this case, Null is the return of a json URL. I just hard coded the json output to test the code._ Please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 4):

`null` is not a keyword in Python. You should either make it a string (e.g. `'name': 'null'`) or use `None` instead

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script to use the json URL instead of add the data directly into the script and then it worked fine.